# Finite State Automata in Prolog

Tags: prolog, state-machine

A program in Prolog describing a finite automata.It needs to have 2 arguments-lists,the first one containing the input([a,b,a,b,a]) for example and the other the output,it should return through whitch states it has been through,following the arrows,for example [1,3,2,4,5]

[image]

Comment: I would like to delicately remind you that Stack Overflow is not a homework service. Please show us what you have attempted and where you have gotten stuck. If you're completely lost, I would suggest you consult a tutorial first and come back with some attempt.

Comment: I`ve gotten only this for now and I have watched some tutorials on Prolog and FSA in it.After this I know I have to use some kind of recursion,got 1-2 ideas,but wont probably work.f(1,b,1).
f(1,a,2).
f(2,a,3).
f(2,b,4).
f(4,a,5).
f(3,b,2).
f(3,a,5).
f(5,a,3).
f(5,b,1).
f(4,b,1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you encode your finite state automata with predicates `f(StartState, EdgeLabel, EndState)`:

```
f(1,a,2).  f(1,b,1).
f(2,a,3).  f(2,b,4).
f(3,a,5).  f(3,b,2).
f(4,a,5).  f(4,b,1).
f(5,a,3).  f(5,b,1).
```

Answering this for a fixed sequence of actions can be done just by chaining queries to `f/3`:

```
?- X1=1, f(X1,a,X2), f(X2,b,X3), f(X3,a,X4), f(X4,b,X5), f(X5,a,X6), L=[X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,X6].
L = [1, 2, 4, 5, 1, 2] .
```

Answering the same query for a list of actions can be done recursively.

Base step is simple: if you start from `Start`, and apply no actions (`[]`), the visited states are `[Start]`.

```
walk(Start, [], [Start]).
```

If you have a sequence of actions, and a sequence of visited states, from `Start` we apply the action `Input` and we reach state `State`, and do recursively the same thing with the remaining actions `Inputs` and the remaining states `States`:

```
walk(Start,[Input|Inputs],[Start|States]) :-
    f(Start,Input,State),
    walk(State, Inputs, States).
```

Test:

```
?- walk(1, [a,b,a,b,a], X).
X = [1, 2, 4, 5, 1, 2] ;
false.
```

Comment: Thank you very much for making it so easy to understand.Works like a charm!